# How do I iterate through a slice of interfaces?

Tags: go

Still new to Go. I'm trying to implement the answer [as suggested here to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26445212/522962). In this case I have an animal interface and a bunch of animal structs. I want to be able to iterate over each animal & get it's language. I've tried a list of pointers but I keep getting an error "y.language undefined (type animal has no field or method language)":

[My playground code](http://play.golang.org/p/k7f7AbgXEf)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type animal interface {
    speak()
}

type dog struct{
    language string
}

func (d *dog) speak() {
    d.language = "woof"
}

var n = []animal{
    &dog{},
}


func main() {
    for _, w := range n{
        x := &dog{}
        fmt.Println(x)
        x.speak()
        fmt.Println(x.language)  // this works
        
        fmt.Println(w)
        y := w
        y.speak()
        fmt.Println(y.language)  // but this doesn't...why??
    }
}
```

EDIT #1: To make my question clearer: Why does x := &dog{} work but y := w does not?
EDIT #2: No love for newbs ;(

Comment: The compile-time error message is absolutely right: your interface only has `speak()`.  If you have an `animal`, according to the interface, all you have is that it can speak.  Trying to get at its language is presumptuous in the technical sense.  If you want to get an animal's `language`, one approach may be to add a `GetLanguage()` to the interface.

Comment: @CharlieTumahai: Maybe I'm being unclear. Why does x := &dog{} work but y := w does not?

Comment: @dyoo I can get the animal's language just fine if I don't use a list: http://play.golang.org/p/IwFEbkoOZk. My question is more like why does x := &dog{} work but y := w does not?

Comment: @CharlieTumahai....makes it much clearer. Thx for your help. Upvoted your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is correct. `y := w` is declaring `y` to be of type `animal` (as your `n` slice is of type `animal`). As your `animal` interface does not contain `language` ... it doesn't know what to do and as such it is an error.

You can assert that it is actually a `dog` pointer by using a type assertion:

```
fmt.Println(y.(*dog).language)
```

..however, I am not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Your structure breaks when you introduce a `cat` that doesn't have a `language` property too. As such, this will also have similar problems (and hopefully demonstrate where your issue lies):

```
type cat struct{
}

func (c *cat) speak() {
    // do nothing
}
```

The answer to your question of "How do I implement a slice of interfaces?" - you need to add whatever you require to the interface in order to process the items "generically". This means turning the `language` property into a `Language()` method and returning it via each individual object that implements the `animal` interface.